# Appending values to existing keys in a dictionary

Tags: list, dictionary, python-3.6

I am working on a website crawler.

The task of this crawler is to look for products and their respective brands.
The written crawler gives me two lists as output.

This works fine so far.
The problem I am facing is that I want to put this two list into a dictionary.
The brands should be the keys and the products the values.
So that I can ask for the brands(keys) on this website and get the products(values) as output.

e.g.:

```
brands = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "b"]
products = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
offer = {}

for i in range(0,len(brands)-1):
    offer[brands[i]] = products[i]
```

desired output:

```
offer = { a: [1, 4, 5] ; b: [2, 6] ; c: [3]}
```

actual output:

```
offer = { a: 5 ; b: 6 ; c: 3}
```

I kinda see that the `for`-loop could be the problem since I am using `equal`-sign, which leads that the values are updating, but not appending.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got to the right mistake
What you need to do is save all the results in a list.

```
brands = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "b"]
products = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
offer = {}

for i in range(0,len(brands)-1):
    if brands[i] not in offer:
        offer[brands[i]] = []
    offer[brands[i]].append(products[i])
```

You can avoid the `if` condition while iterating by using defaultdict. 
[defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is an awesome thing for your use case, without making many changes to your code, the following is the way to do it:

```
from collections import defaultdict

brands = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "b"]
products = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
offer = defaultdict(list)

for brand, product in zip(brands, products):
    offer[brand].append(product)
```